# Reset FCM badge count in iOS Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, push

How do I reset the FCM badge count in iOS swift 4? Right now I call this line of code:

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

which temporarily sets the badge count to 0, but when I receive a new notification the count starts back at the previous count.

I.E. 100, open the app and reset the count to 0 as above. Then when I get a new notification the badge goes to 101.

Is there something different I need to do for FCM? I have ensured that the server is sending the correct badge count.

Comment: Do you use userDefaults to store badge count?

Comment: No, I have not. I don't do anything with the badge count other than reset to 0

Comment: set the badge number to -1, or try to remove all notifications

Comment: @BatyrCan Just tried it, still the same problem

Comment: you can try badge count in userDefaults, handle and set badge manually using userDefaults when notification received.

Comment: @BatyrCan Would this solve it for if the application isn't running? This doesn't only happen while the app runs. Even if the app is completely closed

Comment: receiveRemoteMessage method works in the background or not running mode if you add "Content-availabe=1" to notifications. just try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the issue to be a syntax error when clearing the notification count server side. Thanks for your suggestions.